# How to create file and mount file system as read only?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following `Dockerfile` (I've removed what is not relevant):

```
FROM centos:centos6   
ENV TERM=xterm   
ARG INSTALL_WKHTMLTOPDF=no
ARG WKHTMLTOPDF_VERSION=latest
ARG INSTALL_PDFTK=no
ARG PDFTK_VERSION=latest
ARG PHP_VERSION=default
... 
COPY container-files /
...
EXPOSE 80 9001
WORKDIR /var/www/html
ENTRYPOINT bash -C '/entrypoint.sh';'bash'
```

The `entrypoint.sh` is as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

if [ "$UID" == 0 ]; then
    uid=1000;
else
    uid=${UID};
fi

if [ -z "${GID}" ]; then
    gid=1000;
else
    gid=${GID};
fi

echo "UID: $uid"
echo "GID: $gid"

touch /var/log/xdebug.log
chown apache:root /var/log/xdebug.log   
rm -f /var/run/apache2/apache2.pid   
exec httpd -DFOREGROUND "$@"
```

And finally the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
    erx:
      image: arx_dev
      ports:
        - "80:80"
      environment:
        VHOST_DOCUMENT_ROOT: /var/www/html
      volumes:
        - ./server_logs:/var/log/:ro
```

After build the image and try `docker-compose up -d` it does not start because `touch` can't create the file in a RO filesystem.

```
PS F:\Development\docker\rx> docker logs rx_erx_1
UID: 1000
GID: 1000
touch: cannot touch `/var/log/xdebug.log': Read-only file system
PS F:\Development\docker\rx>
```

How I can create the file and then mount the `/var/log` as read only? I would like to check some logs from the host directly and avoid bash into the container. Any ideas?

Comment: how is your container suppose to write log to only RO filesystem?... I would suggest not to do logs this way. In docker container anything that prints to STDOUT is as log and then you can see it from host with command `docker logs my_container`... so setup your apache to write log to STDOUT

Comment: @MazelTov you're right but how do I output xdebug logs to `STDOUT`? (see [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings) xdebug.remote_log)

Comment: maybe this will help? https://serverfault.com/questions/711168/writing-apache2-logs-to-stdout-stderr

Comment: try putting `ln -sfn /dev/stdout /var/log/apache2/xdebug.log` in dockerfile. Basically anything that dumps to a log file, add a line in dockerfile to symlink that to stdout or stderr so docker can capture it.